# Filter EnumDropDownListFor ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums

In my ASP.NET MVC 5 app I have an Enum:

```
public enum cars
{
  Audi = 1,
  BMW = 2,
  Ferrari = 3
 }
```

In my view I use an EnumDropDownListFor to select one of those values.

```
    Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m=>m.car)
```

Is there a way to filter this list so it only shows eg. Audi + BMW?

Comment: Is EnumDropDownListFor your customer HtmlHelper? . If yes try to filter based on enum value

Comment: EnumDropDownLisrFor is a standard html helper that comes with mvc5. I have no clue where I can filter the data for this dropdownlist.

Answer (score 2):

An old question, if you have the flexibility to change the enums to be power of 2, e.g. 1,2,4,8... you can use bitwise operation on the enum.

```
public class CarModel
    {
        public Cars MyCar
        {
            get { return Cars.Audi | Cars.VW | Cars.Cadalic;}
            set { ; }
        }

        [Flags]
        public enum Cars
        {
            Audi=1,
            Bmw=2,
            VW=4,
            Cadalic=8
        }
    }
```